# Autodesk BIM360 OAuth: who just logged in?

Tags: oauth, autodesk, autodesk-bim360

It is very common in an OAuth environment to have some sort of "Get User" call, to gather info on who just logged in; I cannot find any similar call in BIM 360 and related libraries, however. I can get lists of all the *account users*, or all the *users in a project*, or info on a specific user **IF** I somehow know who that user is; but after a fairly thorough search of all the options, I do not see such a call that gives me the original user. Am I missing something?

UPDATE: I'll answer my own question, since no one else will. The call is GET    https://developer.api.autodesk.com/userprofile/v1/users/@me [https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v1/reference/http/users-@me-GET/]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the endpoint below will tell the user information of the logged user of the oAuth.
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v1/reference/http/users-@me-GET/